# Is this a valid way to make the first node of a linked list to the one after that node?

Tags: c, linked-list

This is what I want to do visually:

```
1->2->3->4  to  2->3->4   (Basically unlink 1)

 struct Courses{
            char *courseName;
            int creditValue;
            Courses *next;
        };Courses;

struct Student{
        char *name;
        int age;
        Courses *list;  //First course (node)
    }Student;

Student student1;

Courses curr = student1->list

curr = curr->next;                  <----- The statement I am questioning
```

What I want to check is whether the line above `curr = curr->next;`is equivalent to making node 1 become what node 1 is pointing at which is node 2. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is right. Remember that you only changed `curr`, though. You didn't change `student1->list`. That still points to the first course. `curr` is just a temporary variable that is now pointing to the second course.

Comment: Another thing to take care of is that if you unlink a node that you dynamically allocated (via `malloc`) then you need to `free` it before you forget about it. Otherwise you'll leak memory.

Comment: I don't know.  What happened when you tested it?

Comment: Hard to answer this question, since you have mixed up values and pointers.  So are we supposed to mention that, or is this _conceptual_ and the fact the code is completely wrong is irrelevant?

Comment: @ArjunShankar My intention is to actually change student1->list without actually typing student1->list. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: @Brandon You could have a pointer to `student1->list`